# Linux pattern to substring the no of RX Packets from an interface of ifconfig

Tags: linux, bash, pattern-matching

I need a linux script to get the number of RX packets form an interface when call ifconfig.

EXAMPLE:

this is ifconfig :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cc:94:d5  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fecc:94d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:71460 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46999 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:67766944 (67.7 MB)  TX bytes:5110629 (5.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4587 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4587 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:471078 (471.0 KB)  TX bytes:471078 (471.0 KB)
```

when calling the script :

```
./getRXpackets eth0
```

the output will be : 71460

the same for the other interface

```
./getRXpackets lo
```

the output will be : 4587

Comment: You might also want to think about using `ip -s link show $iface` instead of `ifconfig` as `ifconfig` is deprecated.

Comment: i've tried `ifconfig | grep 'RX packets' | grep -o "[0-9]"` but it outputs a number on each line and for all the interfaces . i am very new in linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discards the previously characters from printing at the final. `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(ifconfig $1 | grep -oP 'RX packets:\K\d+')
echo $var;
```

Run the above script by,

```
bash ./script eth0
```